# Creating log file. Actionscript

Tags: file, logging, actionscript

Is there any other solution to create logging to file instead of using SharedObject ? 
FileReference works only on Adobe air. File library isn't good because it opens dialog box.

I want to write error logs to file and now I'm using SharedObject, but that's not the main task of the SharedObject.

So if someone have any solutions, would be glad to hear it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe someone will be interesting - i solved this problem.

I wrote a simple WCF service which runs on the same computer. So i can send log messages to this server through localhost and the service writes the logs to the file.

The best part, that it doesn't require an internet connection. ;)